# What do you call the category of groups with surjections (injections)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, category-theory

Take the category $Grp$ and throw out all morphisms that are not surjections.

I think what's left is still a category.

The composition of two surjections is surjective, and identities exist because identities are surjective.

The same should also be true for injections.

**What do you call these, either these specific categories, or categories like these? Is there a name for them?**

Comment: I don't know a name in use. In general doing this leaves you with a less interesting category (usually most limits and colimits will now fail to exist).

Comment: That's frustrating. Here's my motivation for asking. I'm interested in an algebraic property that's closed under surjections. That is, if R has this property, and R subjects onto S, then S has this property. Now, there is no universal property of groups, but I was wondering if there was something else I could use. Like a nice (countable?) family of groups whose closure in the above category is the whole category. That is, a family of groups such that any group in Grp is isomorphi to a quotient of at least one of them. Do you have any suggestions about how I might go about finding such stuff?

Comment: "Closure" is probably not the correct word. I mean something like closure in the poset topology: adding all objects "downstream" of objects in the original family.

Comment: You don't have to leave the ordinary category of groups to ask this question. In any case, there is no such family of groups indexed by a set, because there are groups of arbitrarily large cardinality.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. Then I'll try to focus on finite groups or something I suppose.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is such a family for finite groups?

Comment: Sure: take all finite groups, of which there are countably many. (I don't know an interesting example off the top of my head.)